# Create ionic 4 app inside Angular CLI projects structure

Tags: angular-cli, ionic4, ionic-cli

I am looking for a way to “ionic start” a project and having it in the projects folder of an existing Angular CLI solution (containing a web app and a lib already).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So there isn't an official ionic cli command that can do this, but you can do

```
ng add @ionic/angular
```

In the Project and it will add the necessary pieces to the web app for you.

Other than that, there's always the manual way of installing `ionic/angular`

- `npm install @ionic/angular`
- `npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit`
- add the styles [listed here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/src/schematics/add/index.ts#L40-L58) in your styles array
- include the ionicons assets listed [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/src/schematics/add/index.ts#L60-L70)
- add the native build tasks listed [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/src/schematics/add/index.ts#L72-L100). This is optional if you're planning on deploying to native iOS and native android

Comment: Would this also be the way to add ionic to an existing angular project, where I just want to use a single ionic component?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the putting us to right path!

Small issue I ran into was: when I ran `ng add @ionic/angular`, it installed version 0.2.2 and was throwing the following error

```
The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.
```

I had to run `ng add @ionic/angular@4.6.0` to make it work

Comment: same thing for me, but don't understand why version 0.2.2 is installed by default.